# Map of smooth manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth, connected $n$-dimensional manifolds. Let $M$ be compact and non-empty.

Show that every embedding $f: M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism.

So because $f$ is a embedding we have that $f(M) \subset N$ is a submanifold and especially that $f: M \to f(M)$ is a diffeomorphism. My idea would be to show that $f(M) = N$ and that's somehow related to $M$ being compact but I don't really know how.

Comment: Since $M$ is compact, what do you know about $f(M)$?

Comment: $f(M)$  is also compact

Comment: Right. And as a compact subset of a Hausdorff space, it is ...?

Comment: Then $f(M)$ is closed.

Comment: Yes. And an embedding of a manifold into another manifold of the same dimension is what kind of mapping?

Comment: Smooth, injective map? Sorry, I'm not very used to smooth manifolds.

Comment: I'm after a topological property.

Comment: $f(M)$ is a submanifold? I really don't know what you think of.

Comment: We want to show that $f(M) = N$. We know $f(M)$ is closed. What further knowledge could help us?

Comment: $f$ is a closed map and if $f$ is a bijection it should also be an open map.

Comment: Good. And do the premises tell us that it is in fact an open map?

Comment: Yes, because it is a diffeomorphism. Thanks!

Comment: Well, we want to show that it is a diffeomorphism. What we know is that it is an embedding.

Comment: $f$ is injective and because of the invariance of domain theorem open, I didn't know that theorem though.

Comment: It's good to know that, but here we can get by with the plain old inverse function theorem. The differential (derivative) is by assumption invertible at all points of $M$, so $f$ is a **local** diffeomorphism (hence open). Now, $f(M)$ is an open and closed subset of $N$, ...